# Internet speed through hotspot mobile is slow suddenly

Tags: router, routing, internet-connection, internet-speed

I have been using Netgear AC797S for two years now and it's been fantastic. However, I use a lot of times without battery by plugging it to my laptop. I have an active 4G plan and it's very quick on my phone as always, but not the same on my laptop as I used to have. Just 4 days ago I would check internet speed and it was 30 mega download, not it's 2, but 30 mega remains in my phone for the test. I have one plan and two sim cards, one for my phone and another for my hotspot router. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know what your service plan looks like, here are few things to look for:

1. Try temporarily swapping the SIM cards between your phone and your router and check the speeds. Mobile carriers like to put limitations on "additional" sim cards.
2. Try to get internet off your phone by using "USB tethering" (most mobile phones do have this function). This will reveal if your provider limits "tethered" internet. This is easy for them and some of them do. In this regard, the router does "tethering" as well. Wifi tethering between the phone and the computer will also do for the experiment, but be aware that wifi can introduce its own limitation between the phone and the computer.
3. Try using a known good 4G/LTE modem. Your router may have went bad in a number of ways, including bad settings and hardware aging.
4. Try resetting your router. This may help. Most of these routers have rather medicore software.
5. Try measuring the speed somewhere else. Depending on your environment, subtle things like parked cars on the street sometimes affect wireless connection performance.
6. See your service contract. It may be that some "time-limited promotional extra" has just expired.
7. Try calling your carrier's service line. Yes, they sometimes do help.